# Database table organization with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: database, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm setting up database models and I need to make one to many relationship between them. However the child is always created first and problems araise because foreign key for it is not existing yet.

I have 3 tables, User, Team and Players. 
User can have many teams and one team can have many players. This would all work if I would create User first, then team for it and then add players to it. Because all of this is one-to-many relationship.

However, what I will always have is Team and its Players.
Only when people actually register on my webpage and enter id of their team User needs to be created and conneted with Team that has that id.

This is my code for now, but it's not working because of the reasons mentioned.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    token = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable = True) 
    secret_token = db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True, nullable = True)
    teams = db.relationship("Team", backref="user", lazy=True)

    def add_team(self,team_id,team_name,user_name,youthteam_id,user_id):
        t = Team(team_id = team_id,team_name = team_name,user_name = user_name,youthteam_id = youthteam_id,user_id = self.user_id)
        db.session.add(t)
        db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "team"
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    youthteam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    players = db.relationship("Player", backref="team", lazy=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False)


    def add_player(self,youthplayer_id, youth_name, youth_surname, age, promoted_in, speciality, last_rating,last_pos):
        p = Player(youthplayer_id = youthplayer_id,youth_name = youth_name,youth_surname = youth_surname,age = age,promoted_in = promoted_in,speciality = speciality,last_rating= last_rating,last_pos = last_pos,team_id = self.team_id)
        db.session.add(p)
        db.session.commit()

class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "player"
    youthplayer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    youth_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    youth_surname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Numeric, nullable=False)
    promoted_in = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    speciality = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    last_rating = db.Column(db.Numeric, nullable=False)
    last_pos = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("team.team_id"), nullable=False)
```

So what I would like to achieve is this,
team Alpha exists in database and player1 and player2 are connected to it. When actual person registers on my page he enters his email, username and password. Through ouath I get his user_id from another page. I then make user in my users table and through that user_id he is connected with his team.

Comment: Is this actually more about database design? Why not to have `user_id` in `player` table and allowing it to be null?

Comment: yeah I guess my question boils down to database design. I think you misunderstood or I didn't really explain very well. Player class represents for example Messi, Team would be Barcelona and User would be some random guy on internet that registers on my site.
So Barcelona and Messi need to already exist, but I cannot create them because class Team has foreign key "user_id" that does not exist yet.